# How do I merge consecutive elements in an array subject to a constraint?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings and I want to join consecutive elements if there is a "-" between them.  So, for example, if I have

```
["a", "-", "b", "c"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a - b", "c"]
```

Similarly if the array is

```
["a-", "b", "c"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a- b", "c"]
```

Or if the array is

```
["a", "-b", "c", "d"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a -b", "c", "d"]
```

One exception is that if one of the adjacent tokens already contains a "-", I don't want to merge them together.  So for example, if I have

```
["a", "-", "b-c", "d"]
```

I want the array to remain as

```
["a", "-", "b-c", "d"]
```

Cary helped me come up with this function

```
  def join_some(arr, special_chars_arr)
    arr.drop(1).each_with_object([arr.first]).with_index(1) do |(s,a),i|
      puts "s: #{s} a: #{a.last}"
      if ((special_chars_arr.include?(s[0]) && (i < arr.size - 1 || s.size > 1)) ||
          (special_chars_arr.include?(a.last[-1]) && (i > 1 || a.last.size > 1))) &&
         a.last !~ Regexp.union(special_chars_arr)
        a.last << " #{s}"
      else
        a << s
      end
    end
  end
```

but the problem is if my array is

```
["a", "-", "b-c"]
```

calling join_some(arr, ["-"]) turns things into

```
["a - b-c"]
```

and I don't want to merge adjacent tokens since one of them already contains a dash.  How can I modify my method to do what I want?

Comment: Could you have `["a", "-", "b", "-", "c"]`? If so, what would be the desired result? What about `["a-", "-b"]`?

Comment: The second case should remain as ["a-", "-b"] since the second token already contains a "-".  For the first case, I would like ["a - b - c"], if that's possible.  If its only possible to have ["a", "-", "b", "-", "c"] and all the other cases work, then that's fine.

Comment: It's actually easier to do the first case that way. What about `["-", "a", "b"]` and `["a", "b", "-"]`? Would that be no change, `["- a", "b"]` and `["a", "b -"]` or something else? In other words, for pairwise joins, is `"-"` treated any differently than, say, `"a-"` or `"-a"`?

Comment: For ["a", "b", "-"], it should stay as ["a", "b", "-"], since there are no tokens after the "-" element.  Same with ["- a", "b"] -- it should remain as ["- a", "b"], since there are no elements before the "-".  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def massage(arr)
  arr.drop(1).each_with_object([arr.first]) do |s,a|
    a <<
    case
    when s == '-'
      s
    when a.last == '-'
      ((a.size > 1) && (a[-2] =~ / - [^ -]+\z|\A[^-]+\z/) && (s !~ /-/)) ?
        [*a.pop(2),s].join(' ') : s
    when a.last.end_with?('-') ^ s.start_with?('-')
      a.pop << ' ' << s
    else
      s
    end
  end
end    

examples = [["a","-","b","c"], ["a-","b","c"], ["a","-b","c","d"],
            ["a","-","b-c","d"], ["-", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "-"],
            ["a", "-", "b", "-", "c"], ["a", "-", "b", "-", "c", "-d"]]

examples.each { |a| puts "#{a.to_s.ljust(32)}  \#=> #{massage(a)}" }
["a", "-", "b", "c"]              #=> ["a - b", "c"]
["a-", "b", "c"]                  #=> ["a- b", "c"]
["a", "-b", "c", "d"]             #=> ["a -b", "c", "d"]
["a", "-", "b-c", "d"]            #=> ["a", "-", "b-c", "d"]
["-", "a", "b"]                   #=> ["-", "a", "b"]
["a", "b", "-"]                   #=> ["a", "b", "-"]
["a", "-", "b", "-", "c"]         #=> ["a - b - c"]
["a", "-", "b", "-", "c", "-d"]   #=> ["a - b - c -d"]
```

`^` is both the logical and bit-wise XOR operator. Here the two operands are each `true` or `false` (logical), so it returns `true` if one operand is `true` and the other is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  There is just one thing -- if one of the tokens already has a "-", I don't want to fuse them together.  So in your example, you have ["a", "-", "b-c", "d"], but sicne "b-c" already contains a "-", I'd like the resulting array to remain ["a", "-", "b-c", "d"].

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I fixed that.

Comment: I made a couple of small modifications. Please tell me if the results are all what you want.

Comment: I made a couple of small modifications. Please tell me if the results are all what you want (particularly the last example).

Answer (score 2):

### Append to New Array Based on Terminal Element

There may be more compact ways to express this, but if you're dealing with String values then you can simply loop over each element to decide if it should be appended to the last element of a new array, or added as a separate element. For example:

```
old_array = ["a", "-", "b", "c", "d", "-", "e", "-", "f"]
new_array = []

old_array.each do |value|
  if new_array.last.to_s.end_with? '-' or value.eql? '-'
    new_array.last << value
  else
    new_array.push value
  end
end;

new_array
#=> ["a-b", "c", "d-e-f"]
```

Note that this is fairly robust even when you have more than one dash or minus sign in sequence, which is important if you don't have a fixed sequence length.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for the last case I mentioned --  ["a", "-", "b-c"].  I don't want to merge consecutive elements if one of them already contains my special character.  Your function yeidls "["a-b-c"]" for the above, but the array should remain as  ["a", "-", "b-c"] since the last string contains the special character.